# Upload data base with link onClick

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, pdo

I am having trouble in uploading my database information when I click on a specific link.

It seems that the data is not sent to upload.php

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="btn" onClick="$(this).hide(); myfunc('.$a.', '.$b.')" role="button"> Mylink </a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            function myfunc(a, b)
    {
                          $.ajax({
                            url: "upload.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: {"a": a, "b": b},
                            success:function() {
                             alert( "Done");
                            }
                           });
    }


        </script>
```

**upload.php:**

```
if (isset($_POST['a']) && isset($_POST['b'])) 
    {


        $a = $_POST['a'];
        $b  = $_POST['b'];


        $query1 = $db->prepare('UPDATE  users SET a = a + 1 where uid="'.$a.'"');                                        
        $query1->execute();

        $query2 = $db->prepare('UPDATE  users SET b = b + 1 where uid="'.$b.'"');                                        
        $query2->execute();

        if (!$query1 || !$query2)
        { 
            echo "Erreur SQL";
            exit();
        }

    }
```

Comment: what is $a and $b in myfunc('.$a.', '.$b.')?

Comment: Two parameters that I pass to myfunc. Actually they are integers. Everything is ok and for exemple when I run the code I have like myfunc(1,2) but 1 and 2 are not sent to upload.php so I can't get them to upload my data base

Comment: have tried to alert it inside function myfunc(a, b) ?

Comment: Put a `console.log(a, b)` at the top of your `myfunc`. Is that being called? Is your upload.php script being called? Add `print_r($_POST)` at the top of the php script, and ensure it's being called. Basic debugging...

Comment: think it should be like this myfunc(<?php echo $a ?>,<?php echo $b ?>)

Comment: myfunc is being called. I have the alert "Done" when I click on the link

Comment: I can't figure out why the data are not sent to upload.php

Comment: have you tried my answer @Dilak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st** : Your html should be like this `myfunc(<?php echo $a ?>,<?php echo $b ?>)"`

```
<a href="#" class="btn" onClick="$(this).hide(); myfunc(<?php echo $a ?>,<?php echo $b ?>)" role="button"> Mylink </a>
```

**2nd** :Add error handling part in ajax request

```
  function myfunc(a, b)
    {
          $.ajax({
            url: "upload.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {"a": a, "b": b},
            success:function() {
             alert( "Done");
            },
            error:function(jqXHR,error_string,error){

             console.log(error);

            }
           });
    }
```

**3rd** : use bind_param the values to  avoid SQL injection and integer value should not enclosed by single quotes

```
$query1 = $db->prepare('UPDATE  users SET a = a + 1 where uid=?');   
$query1->bind_param('i',$a);                                     
$query1->execute();
```

**4th**  : In your `upload.php` file your preparing `$query2` first and trying to execute `$query1` i think it was typo please correct it .

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it isnot working too. myfunc is being called and when I clink in the link ther aler "Done" is shown. The probleme is that the data are not sent to upload .php

Comment: if (isset($_POST['a']) && isset($_POST['b'])) 
    {-----} This part is not executed. That's why I am sure that the data are not sent to upload.php

Comment: Do you have a solution @JYoThl ?

Comment: in your upload.php  echo file_get_contents('php://input');   comment all other lines in that file . and change the success function like this success:function(result) {
             alert( result);
            },    to know the value is posting or not . @Dilak

Comment: I solved the problem.   Connection to the database was the problem

Comment: if my answer is useful mark it with green tick it's useful for future user reference @Dilak

Comment: Okay @JYoThl. Thanks

Comment: glad to help you @Dilak